# How do you scroll to the bottom of a Notification Content Extension that is taller than the screen? (Like iMessage)

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, apple-push-notifications, ios10, ios11

With iMessage on iOS 10/11, it uses a Notification Content Extension to show you the current conversation.

[image]
*Note above that conversation starts at the bottom, and user can scroll up to read more messages* (from [iPhoneHacks](http://www.iphonehacks.com/2016/06/ios-10-hidden-features-changes.html))

The content size of the notification is taller than the screen, however, which means you can scroll up and down. This is easily achievable with setting a large `preferredContentSize`.

What I'm confused about though, is how does Apple have it scroll all the way to the bottom of the conversation, and then require you to scroll up? The default behaviour is to have you at the very top, then you can scroll down, but in a conversation view this is obviously not optimal.

I've tried embedding a `UIScrollView`, but Notification Content Extensions don't directly deliver scrolls/taps to the underlying view controller.

Is this a private API? Witchcraft? Something very simple I'm overlooking?